# What CSS would I use to display 1 to 5 rating icons or sprites?

Tags: html, css

I'm running a Joomla site for a client who runs a paranormal investigation team and wants 
to display a set of icons to use for a custom rating system on each case they investigate.

I'd like to be able to write some css in my custom.css that would add stars to the following code such as:

```
<div class="palrating1"><span>Rating:</span></div>
```

and have it display in the browser as:

`Rating: *****`

note: asterisks represent star icons or whatever icons I need to use.

Thank you

Comment: you'll have to give it a data attribute like data-rate="1" to data-rate="10" and assign each with a different background from 1 score to 10.

Comment: what have you already tried?

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want? http://jsfiddle.net/Godinall/wv4tj/
use radio as rating options

```
<input type="radio" id="star5" name="rating" value="5" />
```